# casting flutter in map<String,String>

Tags: flutter, dart

> A value of type `'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'` can't be assigned to a
> variable of type `'Map<String, String>'`. Try changing the type of the
> variable, or casting the right-hand type to `'Map<String, String>'`.

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
map.cast<String, String>();
```

on the map.